# POST a multidimensional array -- Unable to see contents

Tags: php, post, multidimensional-array

I am POSTing a multidimensional array with the following fields in a HTML form:

```
 Member Name:
 <input name="teamMembers[<?php echo $i; ?>][Name]" type="text"
    id="teamMemberName1" maxlength="30" />
 Email: 
 <input name="teamMembers[<?php echo $i; ?>][Email]" type="text"
    id="teamMemberEmail1" maxlength="100" size="40" />
```

I can `print_r($_POST['teamMembers']);` and see the contents of the array, but when I try `echo $_POST['teamMembers[0][Name]'];` I get an "**undefined index**" error.

What am I doing wrong? (I'm sure it's something silly.)

Comment: `echo $_POST['teamMembers'][0]['Name'];`

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST['teamMembers']);` print?

Comment: @Crinsane The contents of the array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have wrong syntax:

```
echo $_POST['teamMembers[0][Name]'];
```

Should be:

```
echo $_POST['teamMembers'][0]['Name'];
```

---

[More Info about Arrays in PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)